# How do I extract standard errors or variation from predicted ordinal logistic regression analyses?

Tags: r, regression, predict

I am undertaking a ordinal logistic regression using R package `MASS`.

For example:

```r
library(MASS)
house.plr <- polr(Sat ~ Infl + Type + Cont, weights = Freq, data = housing)
summary(house.plr, digits = 3)
```

I am using the s3 method `predict()` to obtain the predicted values

```r
test_dat <- data.frame(Infl = factor(rep("Low",4)),
                       Cont = factor(rep("Low",4)),
                       Type = unique(housing$Type))
predict(house.plr, test_dat, type = "p")

        Low    Medium      High
1 0.3784493 0.2876752 0.3338755
2 0.5190445 0.2605077 0.2204478
3 0.4675584 0.2745383 0.2579033
4 0.6444840 0.2114256 0.1440905
```

The result is a table of predicted means for each level of `Sat` given the variables defined in the `test_dat`.

How might I extract the variation around each of these means in the form of a standard error or standard deviation?

Comment: From MASS.pdf under polr: "... there are also profile and confint methods".  So: `confint(house.plr)`.

Comment: @Limey I don't think those methods return the desired confidence intervals. The OP seems to want confidence intervals for the predicted probabilities, not the linear predictor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your predicted values are the predicted probability of each outcome for each observation. It is not the predicted mean on the response scale.

Second, you can use the `marginaleffects` package to get the standard errors for the predicted probabilities and then calculate the confidence intervals yourself. Alternatively, you may implement the non-parametric bootstrap. I implement both in the below. Note that I shifted the order of the columns around in the test data to match the training data.

```
# Packages
library(MASS)
library(marginaleffects)
library(dplyr)

# Create a test set
N <- 4
test_dat <- data.frame(
  Infl = factor(rep("Low", N)),
  Type = unique(housing$Type),
  Cont = factor(rep("Low", N))
)

# Fit ordered logistic regression model
house.plr <- polr(Sat ~ Infl + Type + Cont, 
                  weights = Freq, 
                  data = housing,
                  Hess = TRUE)

# Demonstrate that predict() doesn't provide any measure of variability
# for the predicted class probabilities, as shown in question
predict(house.plr, test_dat, type = "probs")

# Use the marginaleffects package to get delta method standard errors for
# each predicted probability
probs <- marginaleffects::predictions(house.plr, 
                                      newdata = test_dat,
                                      type = "probs")

# Compute CIs from the standard error using normal approximation
probs$predicted - 1.96*probs$std.error
probs$predicted + 1.96*probs$std.error

# Alternatively, use non-parametric bootstrapped confidence intervals.
# note that this does not adjust the weights to a constant sum for
# each bootstrap, although it is easy to implement. You're free to
# determine how to handle the weights, including resampling based 
# on the weights.

# Generate bootstrapped data.frames
set.seed(123)
sims <- 5
samples <- vector(mode = "list", length = sims)
samples <- lapply(samples, function(x){ slice_sample(housing, n = nrow(housing), replace = TRUE)})

# Fit model on each bootstrapped data.frame
models <- lapply(samples, function(x){polr(Sat ~ Infl + Type + Cont, 
                                           weights = Freq, 
                                           data = x,
                                           Hess = TRUE)})

# Get test predictions into a data.frame
probs_boot <- lapply(models, function(x) {
  marginaleffects::predictions(x,
                               newdata = test_dat,
                               type = "probs")
})

probs_boot_df <- bind_rows(probs_boot)

# Compute CIs
probs_boot_df %>% 
  group_by(group, Type.x, Infl, Type.y, Cont) %>%
  summarise(ci_low = quantile(predicted, probs = 0.025),
            ci_high = quantile(predicted, probs = 0.975))
```